# Laravel formbuilder encodes encodes prefix stored in global variable

Tags: laravel, routes, formbuilder

For my routing I add a language prefix stored in the global(?) variable {language}:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{language}', 'where' => ['language' => 'nl']), function()
{
    Route::get('/contact', array('as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'SiteController@contact'));
    Route::post('/contact_send', array('as' => 'contact_send', 'uses' => 'ContactFormController@store'));
});
```

When building my contactform I use the formbuilder:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'contact_send', 'class' => 'form')) !!}
```

I was hoping to get this url so my routing will work

```
action="http://www.website.be/nl/contact_send
```

But instead I get this encoded url:

```
action="http://www.website.be/%7Blanguage%7D/contact_send
```

In another controller I use this which works just fine :

```
return Redirect::route('message', $language)->withErrors($validator);
```

I know I can just use html to create the form but I wan't this done with Form:: so I can learn how to use it.

Any solution?

Comment: *stored in the global(?) variable {language* - yeah, exactly :) You pass a string as the `prefix` value, so... you get a encoded string in the URL back - nothing weird here. If you want to use the current app language in the URL-s you should look into Laravel configuration docs, especially this: `config('app.locale')`, which will give you current locale. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: @lesssugar So I can only get to my route parameter in the controller? The current app language is not defined by the app.locale. It's redirected in my routes.php Route::get('/', function() { return Redirect::to('/nl'); });

Comment: A lot of redirects. Isn't it simpler to **use app.php config** and set the `locale` to whatever you like and whenever you need with `App::setLocale($locale)`? Then you have a language set and you can use `config('app.locale')` helper to set your `prefix` directly in the routes. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization#introduction

Comment: @lesssugar I'll dig into that! If make a multiple language site and let's say I click on the French version, what do you do then? Work with a session variable?

Comment: Depends. If your page is public (no content requiring logging in), I guess you could work only with `locale` setting in app.php. Otherwise, if your user can log in and e.g. choose their UI language inernally, then Session is the most commonly way to store the user language. I would say, figure it out, build, adjust. It will be fine ;)